# Vue js emit event doesn't fire, and code looks ok

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

My emit event stop to work and I cannot understand why.

I have this method in a child component

```
registerVote(){
      this.voted = true;
      this.voted_now = true;
      console.log('vote')
      this.$emit('voted', this.response.data.challenge_id);
    }
```

It's fired after a promise, and i can read in console "vote"

In the parent component I have

```
<imageVote :closed='image_set.closed' :images='sortedImages' :challenge_id="image_set.id" @voted="registerVote"></imageVote>
```

And then my method

```
registerVote: function (value){
      console.log('event')
      this.$store.commit('addCookie', value)
      var cookie_name = this.$store.state.challengeID + "_master_click_votes"
      this.$cookie.set(cookie_name, JSON.stringify( this.$store.state.cookies))
      this.$eventHub.$emit('refreshScore');
    }
```

The method is not fired: why?

Comment: Can you provide a working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or codePen like example? Do you see any error in Console?

Comment: I have tried emit and logged it on parent component as in your code. It works as expected. Is your child component directly inside of parent component?

Comment: @WebMan yes... i try also with event bus, same error. Is the same code I use last year, but now it stopped to work.

Comment: @RobertoPezzali you mention after promise this method runs. `this.$emit('voted', this.response.data.challenge_id);` Did you logged `this.response.data` before emitting it just to be sure there is data? May be there is no data and no `challenge_id`  and app crashes.